# Remainder for an realtime application based on time stored in DB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, service-worker

I'm currently creating a notes like app. In that I need to display a push notification for an note that set it as remain me on some time like 11:00 AM then. Here I use ReactJS, NodeJS, MongoDB

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please provide details of the current state of your code as well

Comment: I'm creating a notes app. In that if user set a particular note as remainder then I need to send a push notification on that time. Time is stored in mongoDB and middleware is nodeJS. I've some idea to send push notification but I don't know how to get that particular note on time i.e I need to fetch the data from mongoDB, right? like trigger. I think it's not a good thing to check whether current time is equal to that time continuously.